# Unable to run spring boot project on macos

Tags: java, spring-boot

**I have a project spring boot java. everything is ok for me to deploy on Windows, kali and ubuntu. But with macos, i face with a problem like this.  Give me a hand with this, will you?**

**java -jar xxx.jar**

```
11:16:02.681 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load config data resource from pattern 'file:./config/*/application.properties'
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.LocationResourceLoader.getDirectory(LocationResourceLoader.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.LocationResourceLoader.getResources(LocationResourceLoader.java:102)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.resolvePattern(StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.java:259)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.resolve(StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.java:245)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.resolve(StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.java:219)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.resolve(StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.java:111)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocationResolvers.lambda$resolve$1(ConfigDataLocationResolvers.java:114)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocationResolvers.resolve(ConfigDataLocationResolvers.java:125)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocationResolvers.resolve(ConfigDataLocationResolvers.java:114)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocationResolvers.resolve(ConfigDataLocationResolvers.java:106)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.resolve(ConfigDataImporter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.resolve(ConfigDataImporter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.resolveAndLoad(ConfigDataImporter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentContributors.withProcessedImports(ConfigDataEnvironmentContributors.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.processInitial(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:230)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.processAndApply(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:217)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:88)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:80)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:100)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:86)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:203)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:196)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:170)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:148)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1507)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:111)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:62)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:362)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298)
    at com.example.demo.WebToolsApplication.main(WebToolsApplication.java:10)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)

**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 'config' is not a directory**
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:97)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.LocationResourceLoader.getDirectory(LocationResourceLoader.java:137)
    ... 42 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Do you have `SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION` defined as an environment variable? From your stack trace you appear to be looking for application.properties on the file system. That should only happen if you have the `spring.config.location` property defined some how.

Comment: If you keep application.properties in the resource folder It will load by default.

Comment: yeah i did it. everything ok for every OS except for MAC

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you add some more details. If possible share the application and bootstrap properties and code.

Answer (score 0):

your have externalized the application.properties file. There are multiple way to fix this issue two of them I'm writing down below:---

**1st way to solve:--**

Create a **config** folder where you placed the the jar file n put the application.properties inside the config folder.

```
Ex- 
if your jar is inside /home/user folder
then your property file should be inside /home/user/config/application.properties
```

then run :

```
java -jar <yourjar>
```

**2nd way to solve:--**

Give the correct path location :--

```
java -jar <yourjar> --spring.config.location=<property file path>
```